# GreaseMonkey/Javascript: continue running after paginating

Tags: javascript, ajax, greasemonkey

I am writing a script to scrape information from a multi-page output.  The output is paginated plain vanilla in the URL: http://example.com/results.php?records_per_page=100&page=1 and the results are AJAX-loaded.

My script includes the [waitForKeyElements](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2625891) utility and starts scraping only after the results have loaded.  After scraping, it triggers the next page, but does not start scraping the next page unless I manually reload the page.

The essence of my script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        example
// @namespace   http://example.com
// @description example
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @grant       GM_getValue
// @grant       GM_setValue
// @include     https://example.com/results.php?record_per_page=*&page=*
// @require     https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

function iterateResults () {
   // iterate through all content DIVs on the page
   for (i = 1; i<=$('div.row_content).length; i++) {
     // parse each DIV
     a = parse($(div.row_content[i]);
     // issue an AJAX request to my server to save the parsed object
     save (a);
   }
   nextPage();
}

function nextPage() {
  patt = /^(.*&page=)([0-9]+)(.*)$/;
  match = document.location.href.match(patt);
  p = 1+match[2];
  nextURL=match[1]+p+match[3];
  document.location = nextURL;
}

/**
 * Wait until all AJAX elements have loaded
 */
function Timer() {
  timer = GM_getValue("timer","")
  window.clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = window.setTimeout(function(){
    GM_setValue("timer","");
    iterateResults();
  },5000); 
  GM_setValue("timer",timer);
}

waitForKeyElements ("div.results_lists", Timer, false);
```

This works well on page=1, but stops after loading page=2 with document.location.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In this case, we may need to see the actual pages and/or the *actual* code for `iterateResults()`.  You have not given us enough information to duplicate the problem. Also, you have [the upvote privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). Use it. ... Meanwhile, try adding this line just before `function nextPage()`: : : `console.log("** ResultsLists: ", $("div.results_lists").first().data('alreadyFound'));`

Comment: @BrockAdams: I have edited to add some detail to `iterateResults()`, even though I fail to see why it would help you duplicate the problem.  The script scrapes the whole first page and then the browser display the next one, so `iterateResults()` successfully runs until its last line which is `nextPage()`.
As for the upvote privilege, I am only an occasional user, I am honoured by the privileges awarded but am reluctant to use them.  In this case particularly, I was not sure whether promoting one owns question would be good or bad etiquette. Guidance always welcome.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer, and it was very simple.  The pages are loaded via AJAX, and adding a dummy function triggered the scraping on the second and subsequent pages:

```
window.addEventListener ("hashchange", fireOnNewPage,  false);

function fireOnNewPage () {
  // console.log ("Fired");
}
```